# Symfony: How to check the data sent by form

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

When I submitted the form with the smyfony4 app, I got the following error.
Since it is an error of the entire form, it is not possible to identify the cause.
I want to debug the value of the submitted form.
What should I do?

I'm sorry for the question like a beginner.

Error

```
shop => Not a valid value.
```

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}

        {{ #The part that issued the error #}}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

            <div class='formGroup'>
                {{ form_label(form.tel, 'TEL') }}
                {{ form_widget(form.tel) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.tel) }}
            </div>
    .
    .
    .
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

```php
        $form = $this->createForm(ShopType::class, $shop, array(
            "method" => "PUT",
            "action" => $this->generateUrl("app_shop_shop_update"),
            "em" => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(),
        ));

        if ($request->isMethod('PUT')) {
            if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
                // save
                $this->get("admin.shopService")->save($shop);
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'I saved my shop profile.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ahi_sp_admin_shop_shop_edit'));
            } else {
                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'The shop profile could not be saved. Please check the input contents.');
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show us what is the error.

Comment: @Pupil Excuse me. I forgot. Please check it because it was added.

Comment: You need to show us the validation constraints you have added in your form or in your entity. And is `$shop` setted before create form ? If this entity is empty, that's why your form don't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony's developer tools were showing the value I was passing when saving, which was the cause of the error.
When saving the basic data of the shop, validation did not work well, and when I tried to update it again, an error occurred with the basic data that is not in the form, so an error message for each error of the form item It seems that there was no display of.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getData()`

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump ($form->getData());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to use it as an example.